# invalid group in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to check anyone not enter yahoo,gmail or any group word.for that i have create regular expression as below but it gives invalid group when i try to put in javascript.

```
if (str.match('/^(.*?(\W|^)(?i)(yahoo|gmail|com)(\W|$))$/')) {
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: You wrapped it with single quotes, thus a string, not regexp anymore.

Comment: Furthermore inline modifiers are not supported in JS regex. There is no real need for an inline modifier here either, you might just want to use `/.../i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is related to `(?i)`, an inline modifier that is not supported by JS regex engine. `(\W|^)` is a common construct in some libraries to denote a word boundary, but in JS, here, it is easier to use a word boundary instead, `\b`.

I suggest

```js
var str = "YaHoo here";
if (/\b(?:yahoo|gmail|com)\b/i.test(str)) {
  console.log("Contains forbidden word!");
} else {
  console.log("Good!");
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:yahoo|gmail|com)` - any of the 3 alternatives
- `\b` - trailing word boundary